# Passing Model to all views mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I m trying to write a web page with mvc for practice reasons mainly.
When the page loads reads an xml file and creates a Model of Stores which contains some settings.

```
<Store>
    <StoreId>459</StoreId>
       <StoreSettings>
          <path1>c:\\mobile\\</path1>
          <path2>c:\\mobile2\\</path2>
     </StoreSettings>
  </Store>
  <Store>
    <StoreId>150</StoreId>
       <StoreSettings>
          <path1>c:\\mobile\\</path1>
          <path2>c:\\mobile2\\</path2>
     </StoreSettings>
  </Store>
</ArrayOfStore>
```

The user choose from a dropdown list the Store he wants(so he chooses the settings for the actions   will take place) the form posts back,i take the selected value fom the list and creating the specific   Model.

I m looking a good way to transfer the specific Model to all other Views.
I mean after select something if click to an other link or button redirecting to an other view,
 ll have to choose again from the list.
I want after he choose something from the dropdownlist keep it(to other views too) until he ll choose something else.(the dropdownlist exist at all views)
Something like global variable which takes the value from what is selected in the dropdown.

What i was thinking to do is to serialise/deserialise the model and send the model from hidden form   but i ll ve to do that for every button and link?

**Edit**
Myform

```
@model Control2.ViewModels.VMStoreList 
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
            <dt>Select Store</dt>

            <dd>@Html.DropDownListFor(p => Model.SelectedValue, Model.ItemsInDropDown, "select store", new { onchange = "this.form.submit()" }) </dd>
```

My model

```
public class VMStoreList
    {

        public Store Store { get; set; }
        public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ItemsInDropDown { get; set; }

        //constructor that initialise the dropdown items
        public VMStoreList()
        {
             XDocument doc = new XDocument();
            doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\gnikolaidis\\Desktop\\Projects\\Control2\\Control\\Settings\\Stores.xml");

            List<Control2.Models.Store> Stores = Control2.Models.HelpFuncs.DeserializeParams<Control2.Models.Store>(doc);
            List<SelectListItem> ItemsInDropDown = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (var Store in Stores)
            {
                SelectListItem i = new SelectListItem();
                i.Text = Store.StoreId;
                i.Value = Store.StoreId;
                ItemsInDropDown.Add(i);
                this.ItemsInDropDown = ItemsInDropDown;
             }
        }

        //This method has the selected value and initialise Store property
        public void Post()
        {
             XDocument doc = new XDocument();
            doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\gnikolaidis\\Desktop\\Projects\\Control2\\Control\\Settings\\Stores.xml");

            List<Store> Stores = Control2.Models.HelpFuncs.DeserializeParams<Store>(doc);
            var g = from s in Stores
                    where (s.StoreId == SelectedValue)
                                       select s;
            this.Store = g.FirstOrDefault();
            this.SelectedValue = SelectedValue;
            int a=6+7;



        }
    }
```

and my action in controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {


            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(VMStoreList Vmobject)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Vmobject.Post();
            }
            return View(Vmobject);
        }
```

Comment: You can move your model up to the outer most view and it will be accessible from child views. If this isn't what you are looking for then you should consider session state, application state or some sort of caching mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 options. For both options you will have to save the user's selection either in the client side (local storage/cookie) or in the server side for it to be rendered back for subsequent requests.

- You can create a `_Layout` page for all views that needs to have the
  selected data displayed by the user and inherit this `_Layout`. You can also consider adding this to the default `_Layout` page given that you need this information in all views.
- You can create a `PartialView` and use `RenderPartial` to show the selected store in the Views that needs to show it.

  In this method, you will have to use `RenderPartial` in all views that you like to show the selected stores information. This means that all ViewModels passed to the normal views must have the items for the `DropDownList` and the Selected Store. This method is useful only when you want to show this information in a handful of views. Because otherwise, you will have to include the extra model info for the stores in all ViewModels.

For example, if you have a `CartViewModel` it will look like below

```
Public Class CartViewModel
{
    Public List<CartItems> Items {get;set;}

    Public SelectedStore SelStore{get;set;}
}
Public Class SelectedStore
{
    Public string SelectedStore {get;set;} 
    Public List<StoreInfo> Stores {get;set;}
}
```

And in your `CartControllers` `Index` view you would call

```
RenderPartial("_UserSelStore", Model.SelStore);
```

Hope you got the idea.

Comment: I tried RenderPartial,looks like good way to go but had problem to call it through controller.

Comment: You don't need to call RenderPartial from within the controller. It must be called from the view. Something like,`RenderPartial("_UserSelection",Model.UserSelection)`

Comment: The partial view should have the model of dropdownlist and stores, which should be created in the controllel by an action with same name.? when my code in main view reaches @{ Html.RenderPartial("Mypartial"); } the partial was executed but had no model.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the selected store in a url and use route params to handle it.

```
Eg: Your view without selected store:

http://yourapp/default/controller/action

Your view with selected store

http://yourapp/selectedstore/controller/action
```

What you have to do is a custom route (in routeconfig):

```
 routes.MapRoute(
               name: "MyStore",
               url: "{store}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", store = "default", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
```

So after you can ask for the selected store in your action Eg:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyStore(string store){
...
}
```

When the user changes the store in the dropdownlist all you have to do is refresh the page with the good store name in the url

Comment: Till now thought Controller/Action/Params was must to mvc, i add a route map to routeconfig and now my url is localhost:4693/default/Oracle but how i replace default with my selected value, i add my model and controller to first post